# After installing Ubuntu Live USB I can only view USB memory

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, ram, format

Trying to partition I formatted the hard drive with wipe now the only memory shown on a Ubuntu Live is the usb...how can I use the rest of the HD?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0    11:0    1  1.5G  0 rom  /cdrom
loop0   7:0    0  1.4G  1 loop /rofs

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M  6.2M  378M   2% /run
/dev/sr0        1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.4G  1.4G     0 100% /rofs
aufs            1.9G  284M  1.6G  15% /
tmpfs           1.9G   29M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  132K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           384M   64K  384M   1% /run/user/999
```

Me:

> Ubuntu 16.4 LTS
>   Memory 3.7 GiB
>   64 bit
>   Disk 2.0 GB

update: Rebooted BIOS/CMOS and now I hard drive showing lsblk:

> ```
>   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>     sda      8:0    1 14.4G  0 disk 
>     └─sda1   8:1    1 14.4G  0 part /cdrom
>     sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
>     loop0    7:0    0  979M  1 loop /rofs
> ```

Comment: Im not trying to restore data, just want to be able to use hard drive, if this is still possible..thanks

Comment: Does Disks or gparted show drive? Does BIOS or UEFI show drive correctly?

Comment: @oldfred I used gparted live and no, it does not show the drive, it will only show the USB live memory. As for BIOS of UEFI, BIOS does not show it as option to choose to boot, as matter of fact, BIOS will show under hard drive boot option my USB.

Comment: If erased it will not show as boot option, but should be in list of drives. If not check connections.  If drive is not in BIOS, it will never be seen by any operating system.

Comment: I see, by checking connections you mean literally? So check the physical data connectors and so..